# Take arrays with specific value

Tags: python

I have a bunch of arrays with 7 entries each.  i want to look at only the arrays with a specific value on their 7th entry.

I have a bunch of arrays that look like:

```
a = [a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,1]
b = [a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,1]
c = [a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,f3,2]
d = [a4,b4,c4,d4,e4,f4,2]
...
...
...
...
```

I want to look at just the arrays with a specific value for their last entry (ie: looking at all arrays such that `array[6] = 1`, which in this case would be array `a` and `b`, but I'm not sure how to do this.  Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a **[list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)**:

```
a = [a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,1]
b = [a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,1]
c = [a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,f3,2]
d = [a4,b4,c4,d4,e4,f4,2]

list_of_lists = [a,b,c,d]
lists_with_1_at_index_6 = [l for l in list_of_lists if l[6] == 1]
print(lists_with_1_at_index_6)
```

**Output:**

```
# Note the real output would have the actual values of variables a1-f1 and a2-f2
[[a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,1], [a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,1]]
```

Comment: exactly the kind of thing i was looking for.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `filter()`:

```
a = list(range(5)) + [1]
b = list(range(5)) + [1]
c = list(range(5)) + [2]

l = [a, b, c]
list(filter(lambda x: x[-1] == 1, l))
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]]
```